# Apexcharts tooltip styles don't applied

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, apexcharts

I'm trying to apply some basic style into my tooltip using ApexCharts in React.

This is my configuration:

```
const options = {
    chart: {
      foreColor: "#ffffff12",
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    colors: ["white"],
    stroke: {
      width: 3
    },
    grid: {
      borderColor: "#ffffff12",
      borderWidth: 1,
      clipMarkers: false,
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true,
        },
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    fill: {
      gradient: {
        enabled: true,
        opacityFrom: 0.4,
        opacityTo: 0
      }
    },
    markers: {
      size: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
      },
      x: {
        show: true,
        format:'HH:mm'
      },
      y: {
        formatter:(value) => `${value}$`
      },
      marker: {
        show: false,
      },
      theme:'dark'
    },
    ...
```

I'm able to see it with the dark default values (like dark background and white font color etc...), but I'm not able to make it work with my own.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add id property to parent of chart element like this.

```
#chartContainer .apexcharts-tooltip {
  color: #000000;
}

#chartContainer .apexcharts-tooltip .apexcharts-tooltip-series-group.active {
  background: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that it would need to use important, that isn't very good... But i didn't find other way to override "apexcharts-tooltip-series-group" style other than using important (It seems there is no option from their API to change this). Thank you for the answer, it helped me so much.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip in ApexCharts can be targetted directly through CSS as it is just an HTML element.
Change the tooltip style by overriding `.apexcharts-tooltip` class and any inner elements inside it.

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.apexcharts-tooltip.light{    
background:red;
color:green;    
}
```